# Too long Socketio communication interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My SocketIO server returns a count of 10 to 0 every second, but my web page only updates the number every 10-15 seconds. However, my NodeJS console well displays this count.

In addition, when I manually reload my web page, my browser shows me the correct figure, but suddenly I have to wait 10-15 seconds for it to display the next digit.

NodeJS part

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;



var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./serv.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});
function envoi(p1){
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('message', p1);
    });
}
main();
function main(){
    var interval = setInterval(loop, 1000);
    var a = 10;
    function loop(){
        if(a<1){
            clearInterval(interval);
            rolling();
        }
        else{
            console.log(a);
            a--;
            envoi(a);
        }
    }
}
function rolling(){
    console.log('ok');
    main();
}
server.listen(8080);
```

HTML/JS part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket.io</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Communication avec socket.io !</h1>
    <div id='r'>Connection..</div>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
       var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = message;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you :)
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problem with your server side socket.io code that could be causing issues.

Your envoi function is creating a new socket.io server in every loop execution.  It is probably returning a cached version, but, you should only invoke listen once. Similar to how creating your http server operates.  It should ideally follow your http server creation.

In the same vein, you should only register to the connection event once following your call to listen.  You should then store the connected socket somewhere or use the io.socket property to retrieve connected sockets.

Your code that prints down the number should look something like this

```
let val = 10;

function pushNumber() {
    io.sockets.emit('message', val); // Sends message to all sockets on default namespace

    val--;
}
```